# bash_login file

Tags: bash, login

I read somewhere, I should be able to find *.bash_login* file in my home directory.

Well, I cannot find it. Where could be the problem ?

I have only these files :

[image]

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Here https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User accounts on Ubuntu don't have a `.bash_login` file by default, but you can just create one if you want. It's a simple shell script file with no special requirements.

Alternatively, if it is not specific to Bash only or you don't use any other shells anyway, you can also make the modifications you want to your `.profile` file, which is also read by login shells, right after the `.bash_login` one, if it exists.

For more information, see `man bash` and search for the `INVOCATION` chapter.